# Bit masks types in modern C++

Tags: c++, bitmask

What's the modern way of declaring bit masks types in modern C++? Is there a recommendation for this?

```
// old C, not recommended in C++
#define COLOR_BLUE 1 << 0
#define COLOR_RED 1 << 1

 // Prefer enum class instead of enum, also it's a good practice to use unsigned, not enums(int)
enum Color 
{
  blue = 1 << 0;
  red = 1 << 1;
}

// a class with access only to these members
// additional lines to delete unnecessary data, delete ctors, etc
class Color
{
public:
  static constexpr unsigned int blue = 1 << 0;
  static constexpr unsigned int red = 1 << 1;
  Color() = delete;
}

bitset.set(Color::blue);
```

Comment: OK, you want to replace them anyway, but *if* using macros, make them safe: `(1 << X)`, and for bit masks, unsigned might be more approprate (`(1U << X)`).

Comment: asking for recommendations is offtopic. You could ask eg if there is a recommendation on bitmasks in the [cppcoreguidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md), but then you could simply browse it yourself ;)

Comment: Try `unsigned int c = Color::blue | Color::red;` (which is what one would typically want to do with bit flags)  with `enum class Color;`... I personally would go with the constexpr constants, you have better control over the resulting type than with (classic) enums. But if `Color` has no other use than providing a scope, you should use a namespace instead of a class as "wrapper".

Comment: @Aconcagua, in most of the code I use `if var & Color::blue`, which enum class will not work. Perhaps a namespace, hmm.. @user463035818 I did not find any recommendations on the official C++ guidelines or in any of the known books (Sutter, Meyers)